# fpdf doesn't support utf8_general_ci collation and utf-8 encoding in php

Tags: fpdf

I have one MySQL database named ddms and one table named district in there.

i am trying to retrieve data from my database in pdf using fpdf library of php.

my data is stored in utf-8 encoding and `collation is utf8_general_ci.

data is in gujarati shruti font.

but whene i run php script it shows me something like this : àª¸à«•àª°àª¤

Comment: http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm

Comment: @DhairyaLakhera I have checked this there is noting regarding the Gujarati font I need for Gujarati fonts

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through